# Grounding Power at an Isolated Outbuilding?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I am looking to draw off some electricity from an outbuilding. It looks like we have an 60 amp fuse hooked up to 3 wires binging power to this outbuilding. So no ground standard 240v power. I don't own this building or the land it is on, so don't really want to mess with it.

This is in Canada.

I want to take power from this outbuilding breaker box to another location, right beside it. Are their any best practices for this? My understanding is that I would want to be running a ground wire between as well as installing more grounding rods at the new location. But it seems like the one will be impossible. I can drop grounding rods down to ground water easily, or even chuck some in nearby ponds or wells.

The Current Setup:
The utility sends in 3 wire standard 240V to Building A (200amp fuze).
We installed a single grounding bar next to this for ground.
It looks like neutral and ground are connected, my understanding is this is not always how it is done.
This was all certified and signed off on like 25 years ago.

We then take a 60 amp fuse and send ground and a 4-4-4 copper wire to some shutoff with cylindrical fuses like 20 feet away. Then just the 4-4-4 gets sent with a defunct water line through a 4" perforated drainage tile , as was the code at the time.

This ends up in building B, without any ground, about 180 feet away.

Comment: Are those 3-wires a *service* from the utility, or a *feeder* from another building on your property?

Comment: What country are we talking about and do you have applicable codes? Without more information we cannot answer the question; It is a bit confusing 1 fuse 3 wires no ground? Is it three phase? what voltage?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The three wires are -120V, +120V and neutral. So single phase, standard 240v power.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Power from the utility enters into building 1 at its breaker box (standard 240v). This goes off a 60amp to a 2nd building and breaker box. I want to take it a third time a very short additional distance to a third breaker box.

Comment: @Gil I updated the question to hopefully answer all your questions.

Comment: Are those 3 wires coming into building 2 in a conduit, or directly buried?

Comment: I can try to ask and see if anyone remembers. The wires are in a conduit while in the building, but I am not sure what they are doing while in the ground

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The wire is in a conduit with the now unused water line as was the code back then.

Comment: For example, Solar power installations are often made at locations that do not have utility  access. Their is no central grounding wire entering the location. Is their any way I could copy whatever they do for ground?

Comment: @Jonathon -- what size is the conduit in question, and I take it you're dealing with that 4-4-4 URD (Direct Burial) cable from your other post?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Just found out a bunch of new information and posted an update that should answer all of these questions and more. No idea if it is direct burial cable or not as it has no markings.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a SWAG, I do not know the Canadian code. It sounds like you have single phase power, phase A, Phase B and Neutral through a two pole breaker. The transformer that supplies this has either two secondary windings with one of each connected as a center tap or a center tapped winding with the neutral on the 'center tap'. These two phases are 180 degrees apart. Between neutral and either phase you get 120VAC. Between the phases you get 240VAC. In the US this neutral will typically be grounded at the pole and at the entrance panel with a 4th wire called ground (green or bare), in my case it is the transfer switch for the standby generator. Normally etucetly bonded to a ground rod driven into into the ground to make electrical contact with the earth at the entrance. The ground wire must be continuous, not spliced although etucticly bonding may be acceptable. This varies with location and local requirements. I have 5 rods in an array. We bond the neutral to the ground at only the main entrance panel. The end result we have for a typically outlet one of the phases supplying power through a breaker (type varies by location), a neutral wire and the ground wire, three in total.  I do not know the code in canada so you should check with the local authority. You may have to run a seperate wire or change the cable to source the ground from the main panel or you may just be able to add a ground rod. In either case do not use the neutral for a safety ground.